# Can I persist application state without using file or database in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My question is "Is there any way to save state of activity, that can be used when application has been restart.".

In my application, I had been override onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState to save and restore my instance state.

I also used SharedPreferences to save the state. But I found that SharedPreference has been clear when I pressed Back Buttaon and restart my application.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(MY_APP, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

    editor.putString(USER_NAME, name.getText().toString());
    editor.putInt(COUNT_STATE, count);

    editor.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(MY_APP, MODE_PRIVATE);

    name.setText(pref.getString(USER_NAME, ""));
    count = pref.getInt(COUNT_STATE, 0);
}
```

I also know that this problem has been solved if I used external or local storage.
I want to know that can I persist application state without using file or database.

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState()` is not 100% guaranteed to be called, can you add some logs in that method and see if it's being called in first place.

Comment: Thank you Yazan. I will add the log in onSaveInstanceState method and I will check that this method has been called before back button pressed.

Comment: Hi Yazan, onSaveInstanceState() doesn't work when I pressed back button. But it works when I change screen rotation. I will try to override onBackPressed method. I will call onSaveInstanceState in this method.

Comment: that's what i thought, but note that it's not good idea to call lifecycle methods, instead put the code that write in `SharedPreferences` inside a new method, say `saveMyState()` and call this method from `onSaveInstanceState()` and from `onBackPressed()`

Comment: Hi Yazan, I'd tried that calling the same codes from both of onSaveInstanceState and onBackPressed method. It doesn't work after pressing back button. So I tried that to change the behavior of back button pressed. But I think this way is not a good way. 
After restart my device my state has been loosed.
Do I need to save my state in a file or db?

Comment: i will post an answer of what i think you have to do

Answer (score 2):

at `onBackPressed()` you need to store your state
and when activity created `onCreate()` you need to restore it

```
private void saveMyState(){
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(MY_APP, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

    editor.putString(USER_NAME, name.getText().toString());
    editor.putInt(COUNT_STATE, count);

    editor.commit();
}

private restoreMyState(){
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(MY_APP, MODE_PRIVATE);
    name.setText(pref.getString(USER_NAME, ""));
    count = pref.getInt(COUNT_STATE, 0);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    saveMyState();
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //init views, buttons, textViews (findViewById)...
    //do other works ...
    //:
    //:

    //then try to restore state (if saved)
    restoreMyState();
}
```

if you want you can do the same call `saveMyState()` and `restoreMyState()` at 
`onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` in case of orientation changed

i think this will cover all the cases you want.

PS: using `SharedPreferences` will write/read to a file, **under the hood** so you are already using file if you are using `SharedPreferences`

Comment: Than you @Yazan. This answer is very helpful for me.

Comment: no problem, please consider accepting this answer if it's what you need

Answer (score 0):

For my question, I try to change behavior of Pressed Back Button by overring onBackPressed.
In this method I write moveToBackTask(true).

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

My application state has been restored when I pressed back button and restart application.
But I think that this state can't be restored when I restart my device.

Do I need to store my state in a file?